# How can I update multiple documents and add a new field computed from another in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I've got multiple documents with the field `text` which has date/time string (e.g. '2020-12-14 22:43:56') or some text. I want to add in all documents a new field which will be calculated from `text` and contains ISODate or null. I've got this script which should do this and it works in projection, but doesn't work with update operation:

```
db.test.updateMany(
    {date: {$exists: false}},
    {$set: {
        date: {$dateFromString: {
                       dateString: "$text",
                       format: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
                       onError: null
                       }}
        
    }
    })
```

But it throws an error:

```
WriteError({
    "index" : 0,
    "code" : 52,
    "errmsg" : "The dollar ($) prefixed field '$dateFromString' in 'date.$dateFromString' is not valid for storage.",
    "op" : {
        "q" : {
            "date" : {
                "$exists" : false
            }
        },
        "u" : {
            "$set" : {
                "date" : {
                    "$dateFromString" : {
                        "dateString" : "$text",
                        "format" : "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
                        "onError" : null
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "multi" : true,
        "upsert" : false
    }
})
```

What I'm doing wrong? What is a correct way of doing this?

Comment: try adding update part inside array `[{ $set: .. }]` for more information refer [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$dateFromString` is an aggregation function, you cannot use it directly in `updateMany`. Luckily (starting in MongoDB 4.2) `updateMany` accepts also an aggregation pipeline, not just an update document.

Would be this one:

```
db.test.updateMany(
    {date: {$exists: false}},
    [
        {$addFields: {
           date: {$dateFromString: {
                       dateString: "$text",
                       format: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
                       onError: null
                       }}
          }
       }
    ]
)
```

`$addFields` is just an alias for `$set` - but it visualizes the difference between update operator [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/index.html) and the aggregation stage [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/set/index.html)

See [Update with an Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/index.html#updatemany-behavior-aggregation-pipeline)